# Custom Control Xaml Elements

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I have

controls :

ControlX :IControlX and ControlY:IControlY

ControlZ has a List Property of ControlX

Interfaces :

IControlX and IControlY:IControlX

The Tags I am getting is:

```
<ControlZ>

        <ControlY>

            <ControlX></ControlX>

             <ControlX></ControlX>

        </ControlY>

</ControlZ>
```

Here I can access the ControlY in the List but Not able access Control X.

But If I change the tag sequence as :

```
<ControlZ>

        <ControlY> </ControlY>

        <ControlX></ControlX>

         <ControlX></ControlX>       

</ControlZ>
```

I can Get the all the object in the list.

But it is not logical so I need to maintain the tag sequece.

Can you please suggest me . How can I get access of the inner tags ?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. XAML does not allow you to access properties of properties unless you initialize them in XAML.

```
<Control:MyControl>

  <Control:MyControl.Property1>

       <!-- Assuming that Property1 is of type MyOtherControl -->
       <Control:MyOtherControl Property="somevalue" />

 </Control:MyControl.Property1>

</Control:MyControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set a value of a property of `Property1`, you have to instanciate it first. Let's say that `Property1` os of type `Property1Type` which exists in the same namespace, and the type of the inner property (`Property`) is `InnerPropertyType` which is also in the same namespace. You code should be something like:

```
<Control:MyControl>
    <Control:MyControl.Property1>
        <Control:Property1Type>
            <Control:Property1Type.Property>
                <Control:InnerPropertyType />
            </Control:Property1Type.Property>
        </Control:Property1Type>
    </Control:MyControl.Property1>
</Control:MyControl>
```

this is similar to, for example:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.BorderBrush>
    <ImageBrush>
      <ImageBrush.Transform>
          <ScaleTransform ScaleX="5"/>
      </ImageBrush.Transform>
    </ImageBrush>
  </ListBox.BorderBrush>
</ListBox>
```

This should solve some of the issues, if other persist, please update your question ;)

Hope this helps :)